# Does it exist function in Python which returns angle from trigonometric function value?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

In math package, there are trigonometric functions which return value and takes as a parameter angle (in degrees or radians). For example,

> math.tan(math.radians(45))
>
> 0.9999999999999999

Is there exist a function in Python which takes as an argument value of a trigonometric function (eg. tangents) and return angle?

Comment: You mean the inverse trigonometric functions? Such as arctangent?

Comment: How can it be you missed `acos`, `asin` and `atan`? They are in the official documentation in the [same section](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions) as the `tan` function you already found.

Comment: @AndrewLi: The question refers to the "math package" and asks "Is there exist a function in Python" so it does seem to be about programming. It may be a duplicate or have other problems, however, but I cannot say.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sure, but conceptually it's about inverse trigonometric functions. The question suggests that they don't know about them, which would make the question more math related IMO.

Comment: @AndrewLi: this is fully a programming question, related to the Python language and modules. Anyway, my downvote to the OP as the inverse trigonometric functions are listed in the doc very visibly with the direct ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the angle in degrees, you can use

```
math.degrees(math.atan(1))
```

This gives the answer

```
45.0
```

in the interactive console.

However, be aware that this returns *one angle* that gives that trig ratio--there are also infinitely many others that give the same ratio. For that very example, 225° has the same tangent. For the tangent ratio, the other angles differ from the returned angle by a multiple of 180°.

The inverse of `sin()` is `asin()` and the inverse of `cos()` is `acos()`. Like tangent, they return one angle that gives that ratio. Angles that differ by a multiple of 360° will also give the same trig ratio. For sine, you can also subtract one of those angles from 180° to get another such angle, and for cosine you can get one by taking its negative.

For sine and cosine, if the supposed ratio is not between -1 and 1 there is no real answer at all, and Python will return an error.